# Создание пользовательского размера изображения (Не могу зарегистрировать мой размер)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Мне нужно изменить размеры изображений. Я создаю собственный плагин (а не тему). Вот что я использую:

```
function myplugintest_custom_image_size_500_x_500() {
    add_image_size( 'myplugintest-size-500-500', 500, 500, 0 );
}
add_action( 'init', 'myplugintest_custom_image_size_500_x_500' );
```

Затем мне нужно получить ссылку на изображение для отображения в моем пользовательском блоке (в myplugintest.php).

```
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url($product->get_image_id(), 'myplugintest-size-500-500', false);
```

Но я получаю оригинальное изображение с суффиксом scaled.

Это работает, если я использую уже зарегистрированные размеры, например:

```
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url($product->get_image_id(), 'woocommerce_single', false);
```

В чем может быть проблема и как мне зарегистрировать мой размер?

Upd 1:

Если погружаться в функцию `wp_get_attachment_image_url` все глубже, то можно найти `wp_get_attachment_metadata`, которая возвращает `$meta`. В `$meta` есть массив `sizes` который содержит все зарегистрироанные размеры, но там нету моего размера.

Comment: Не нужно ставить не относящиеся к вопросу теги. Особенно  php, если интересует ответы на вопросы. Некоторые пхписты с большой репой большие любители закрывать вопросы по ВП, в которых они не понимают.

Answer (score 1):

> Но я получаю оригинальное изображение с суффиксом scaled.

Это говорит о загрузке [огромных изображений](https://wp-kama.ru/id_12989/suffiks-scaled-u-kartinki.html)

Для вызова же миниатюры нужно использовать не [`wp_get_attachment_image_url`](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_get_attachment_image_url), а `the_post_thumbnail` или `get_the_post_thumbnail`.

И внимательно изучаем параметры [функции](https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_image_size)

`add_image_size( 'myplugintest-size-500-500', 500, 500, false );`

`false`, а не `0`.

И вешать не на `init`, а на  `plugin_loaded`

Comment: Сделал изменения, но ситуация не изменилась. Я все равно получаю большую картинку. Нужно ли переустанавливать плагин или тему?

Comment: @Alex если изображение было загружено на сайт до того как Вы зарегестрировали image size, то Вам нужно будет перегенерировать миниатюры.